# Normal post and Ajax post in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to call post action method in controller. my razor view is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
@Html.TextBox("count")

// here i have many controls 

<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(string count)
{
// i will do many business related actions
return View();
}
```

My question is, can i use normal post call by clicking submit button or shall i use ajax post method?
Which method of calling is good in mvc3 and why?

Comment: Great guide here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3

Answer (score 1):

You must know the difference between `Normal post` and `ajax`

if you dont want to refresh your page then use ajax i.e you have to update content dynamically and stay on that page , otherwise use normal post

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are fully supported, and the choice depends on your scenario.

Comment: if we use normal post call we have to have to bind the model again to view for persisting the modified data.if we use ajax call, values that modified by user will be persist for subsequent ajax requests without binding model?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ajax post method if you don't want to reload all your page on submit. Ajax allows you to make some partial refresh, so you refresh only a part of your page WHILE the normal post call loads an entire page(including headers and some other content that may not be changing).

Answer (score 0):

garethb  has given an answer in this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3.

the answer is

Ajax forms are suitable in situations, where you need to do modify or save operations asynchronously , without redirecting to any other forms.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MVC of ASP.NET, which is server-side. Posts are issued by the Javascript written on the client-side. Posts are supported by your server-side, so you can use "normal" or ajax posts as you like.